# compile libconfig++ with -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++

Tags: compilation, linker, libtool

I'm trying to compile [libconfig++](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) version 1.4.8 with

```
make LDFLAGS='-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
```

but this doesn't seem to work since I'm still getting:

```
$ readelf -d lib/.libs/libconfig++.so | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
```

I'm noticing that the second-to-last compile step for the so file contains my LDFLAGS:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2 -Wall -Wshadow -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -version-info 10:3:1 -no-undefined -static-libgc
c -o libconfig++.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libconfig___la-libconfig.lo libconfig___la-scanner.lo libconfig___la-grammar.lo libconfig___la-scanctx.lo li
bconfig___la-strbuf.lo libconfig___la-libconfigcpp.lo
```

Whereas it appears like the very last one doesn't:

```
libtool: link: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7
/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libconfig___la-libconfig.o .libs/libconfig___la-scanner.o .libs/libconfig___la-grammar.o .libs/libconfig___la-scanctx.o .libs/libc
onfig___la-strbuf.o .libs/libconfig___la-libconfigcpp.o   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linu
x-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/l
ib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x
86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libconfig++.so.9 -o .libs/libconfig++.so.9.1.3
```

Could this be the cause of it, and in that case, how would I go about fixing/working around it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the libconfig++ Makefile is simply ignoring LDFLAGS, since I don't see '-static-libstdc++' being picked up at all.

Try this:

```
CXX="g++ -static" make
```

Or just put the LDFLAGS *before* make, instead of after it.

Comment: True that -static-libstdc++ isn't there but -static-libgcc is, which isn't a default option.  libtool appears to ignore switches it doesn't understand.  It does understand -static and the -lstdc++ that g++ added but doesn't understand -static-libstdc++.  I can see -static working for the OP but my situation is perhaps more complicated than the OP's.  I want other libs to still be dynamic.  Using gcc rather than g++ and passing -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

-static-libgcc is GCC option, not a linker option.  Put it in CFLAGS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you $(LD_FLAGS) are included in you linking call.

On a side note, your linker could be picking up a dynamic (*.so) library that prevents -static-libstdc++ and -static-libgcc to be used. Every library calling libgcc and libstdc++ should be linked statically (if there is a static version available, of course).

Comment: Downvoted "not useful". I'd be interested to hear your criticism. This was a real situation I came across and I found the solution with the method described above.